# Using Shiro with OAuth and JWT

Tags: java, spring, oauth, shiro

We are using shiro in our application, and the session are saved in the database for scale. And we have our own accounts databse, so far so good.

This is the core security components:

1. DatabaseRealm

Vvalidate user by `UsernameAndPasswordToken` and the password in the database, retrieve the permissions fro the database.

2. DatabaseSessionDao

Extends the `CachingSessionDAO`, for create,read,delete sessions from the database.

3. DefaultWebSessionManager

Shiro built in components.

Now we have to make two kinds of improvement:

1. Integrate the OAuth login

For example, user should be able to  login by `Google` or `Facebook` or their own accounts registered in our application.

Then I wonder how  can we re-use the existed security components like the `DatabaseRealm`, since the realm will check the `AuthenticationInfo`'s credentials which is not avaiable in the OAuth context:

```
@Override
protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token) throws AuthenticationException {
    SimpleAuthenticationInfo info = null;
    if (token instanceof UsernamePasswordToken) {
        UsernamePasswordToken uToken = (UsernamePasswordToken) token;
        User user = queryUserByName(uToken.getUsername());
        info = new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword().toCharArray(), getName());
        if (user.getSalt() != null) {
            info.setCredentialsSalt(ByteSource.Util.bytes(user.getSalt()));
        }
    } else if (token instanceof OAuthUserToken) {
        OAuthUserToken oToken = (OAuthUserToken) token;
        String type = oToken.getOauthType();
        String openId = oToken.getOpenID();

        //then what should I do to make the `Credentials` check passed?
    }
    return info;
}
```

How to fix this?

2. Using JWT(Json Web Token)

The sessions are saved to the database for cluster deployment at the moment, however we found that it may slow our response, also we need to provide api for the mobile paltform, so we try to use `JWT`.

While it seems that shior use `cookie + session` to identify if user have been authenciated or not. I have no idea how to replace that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

It may be better to add new `Realm` / `Filter` / `Login url for redirection`.

`GoogleRealm`

```
public class GoogleOAuthRealm extends AuthorizingRealm {
    ...

    public GoogleOAuthRealm() {
        //OauthToken implements AuthenticationToken to hold code
        setAuthenticationTokenClass(OauthToken.class);
    }

    ...

    @Override
    protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token) throws AuthenticationException {
         OauthToken tk = (OauthToken) token; 
         String authCode = (String) tk.getPrincipal(); 
         //1. fetch token by posting code to google 
         //2. validation & parse token
         //org.apache.shiro.authz.SimpleAuthorizationInfo
         SimpleAuthenticationInfo info = new SimpleAuthenticationInfo();
         //set permission manually
         return info;
    }
    ...
}
```

config `GoogleRealm` in `securityManager`, and redirect to a new `url` after google login success.

```
public class GoogleAuthenticatingFilter extends FormAuthenticationFilter

<property name="filterChainDefinitions">
    <value> 
        ...
        /login/googleLogin = GoogleAuthenticatingFilter
        ...
    </value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

As neuo wrote above, use a different realm for OAuth and then do some wiring up on the back end to reconcile the user credentials. For your scaling and performance, I’d suggest using something like Redis as a session cache - that will save you having to persist sessions in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Re-Using Existing Components

Consider the construct in which you are working, you probably do not want to reuse the `DatabaseRealm` for other authentication schemes. Rather create individual realms for Google, Facebook, etc.

This way you will be able to control what `AuthenticationToken`and `AuthenticationInfo` will be used in each Realm.

JWT/Cookie Session

From what you decribe I think you would likely want to create a RESTful API for your mobile platform. The REST spec requires that the server does not maintain, and more importantly not rely on server-side state.
Fortunately shiro allows you to configure endpoints that do not create a session when a request is received. More details on session management [here](https://shiro.apache.org/web.html#session-management)

Considering the above, session tracking becomes irrelevant, and you could use the JWT token as a form of Bearer token to tacitly authenticate the user on every request. Be sure to consider the security short-falls of the Bearer token, which may be mitigated by always using an encrypted connection.